# Failed to run the dA Platform Trial VM

Tags: apache-flink

I downloaded the "dA Platform Trial VM", however I failed to run it in virtual box ,it seems no process running for da platform , below pic is the details.

[image]

Comment: Try running `kubectl get deployment daplatform-appmanager` to see if it is currently running. Sadly it can take quite a while to start up since there are a lot of dependent services.

If kubectl shows no instances available, then try listing the pods, using `kubectl get pods` and find the one named `daplatform-appmanager-...` that is in the `CrashLoopBackOff` state. We want to check the logs to see why it's not running, which you can do using `kubectl logs <pod-name-here>`.

Comment: How recently did you download the VM? If you've had it for a while already, it could be that the trial license bundled with the VM has expired already. In which case, you'll need to download a new copy of the VM to continue using it.

Comment: I downloaded on 8/7/2018, just two days ago.

Comment: Hi. I just run the VM again, now everything is okay, maybe just like you said " it can take quite a while to start up since there are a lot of dependent services."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dA Platform trial VM (as of version 1.1) takes quite a while to start. It might take up to 3 minutes till all the services are available in the virtual machine.

Comment: Thank you for your info.BTW, when using the dA Platform , there is just single job manager running  and even no need to install the Zookeeper cluster  to achieve the HA,right? As the Kubernetes would make sure the single job manager  high availability?

Comment: Hey, there is only a single JM running per Flink job, yes.  However, in the VM, JobManager HA is not enabled by default. Zookeeper is not part of dA Platform at the moment.
To achieve HA, you need to set up ZK, configure it with the Flink cluster. Then Kubernetes will restart failed JobManagers, and ZK will be used to store the state of the JM to restore.

Comment: If the state of the JM can be store to HDFS,? So we don't need to depend on the Zookeeper?

Comment: Hey, you need to have ZK in place to use JM HA. ZK is used for leader election and for storing recovery metadata.

Comment: I mean using Kubernetes with single JM, as Kubernetes make sure the availability of the JM, so no need to use the ZK again for leader election ,right? In that case if we can store the metadata to HDFS, then when Kubernetes discovery there is a failed JM, it can restart the another mirror JM , then the new JM would get the metadata from HDFS, so no ZK needed, is it make sense?

Comment: You are right, that this could work. However, at the moment, dA Platform requires Zookeeper.
We are aware of this limitation, and we plan to address it with the next release of dAP (version 1.3), scheduled later this year.